# Empty RouteData in IHostBufferPolicySelector's context in WebApi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to upload large files in WebApi 2. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api) (which is the same recipe used in the webapi 2 cookbook) where you register a host policy

```
public class NoBufferPolicySelector : WebHostBufferPolicySelector
{
   public override bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext)
   {
      var context = hostContext as HttpContextBase;

      if (context != null)
      {
         if (string.Equals(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), "uploading", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;
      }

      return true;
   }
}
```

However context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData is basically a dummy object with no route data set.

Is there another method for finding the RouteData in webapi 2 from an HttpBaseContext, or possible another method to get deal with bufferless uploads?

Answer (score 1):

Your post is already a bit old, but recently went through the same problem.

Projects with Owin Host (my case and maybe yours) use OwinBufferedPolicySelector class that already does the job, so do not need to overwrite the class.

OwinContext not exposes RouteData as HttpContextBase.

https://books.google.com.br/books?id=7aE8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=override+WebHostBufferPolicySelector&source=bl&ots=fvV5SWVsJG&sig=I5t4MBOXdPbgFV4mBCI_kWLWkRw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=oheIVev2N-TgsASS2IDgCQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=override%20WebHostBufferPolicySelector&f=false

Comment: Thanks, nice find! To quote from the link: "Enabling bufferless input is not required with OWIN host, since OwinBufferPolicySelector is streaming requests by default."

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Owin, you are already using bufferless input so you don't need to make any changes.

By default without Owin, the `WebHostBufferPolicySelector` is used, which has buffering set to `true` for input streams:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/WebHostBufferPolicySelector.cs

```
public virtual bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext) {
    if(hostContext == null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("hostContext");
    }

    return true;
}
```

When you use the Owin middleware layer, `OwinBufferPolicySelector` is used instead of `WebHostBufferPolicySelector`, which has buffering set to `false` for all input streams:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/OwinBufferPolicySelector.cs

```
public bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same issue and solved it by commenting out the call to "MapHttpAttributeRoutes" method on HttpConfiguration instance. I do not know why it interfere with RouteData.

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes 
        //Enabling of below cause empty RoutData in NoBufferPolicySelector class.
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
```